# How generate a mixin pug (or include pug file) from function javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Hell everybody

I would like to display a mixin pug or include a pug file when from a javascript function. How can I do this please?

Thanks in advance!

///////////////
SOLUTION FOUND !
///////////////

Sorry but I finally found my happiness!
I'm going to share my solution so that maybe the next one can be helped. :)
I finally used the reference API of PUG:

```
pug.compileFileClient(chemin, ?options) 
Compilez un fichier de modèle Pug en une chaîne de JavaScript qui peut être utilisée côté client avec le runtime Pug.
```

Part back node.js:

```
// Compiler le modèle en une chaîne de fonction
var jsFunctionString = pug.compileFileClient(path.join(__dirname, '../views/src/template.pug'), {nom : "myTemplateName"}) ;
// Peut-être voulez-vous compiler tous vos modèles dans un fichier templates.js et le servir au client
fs.writeFileSync ("yourFileJSToUseIt.js", jsFunctionString) ;
```

In the console:

```
npm install pug-cli -g
pug --client --name myTemplateFunction my-pug-file.pug
```

And finally, part front js:

```
var html = window.myTemplateFunction ({auteur : authorValue}) ;
```

Thanks anyway and sorry for the lack of information in my question... :(
Thanks Graham too :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow is a community where you are expected to post at least one attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the solution, and instead post the solution as an answer. Questions should not be edited to include solutions.